# How to define permission in Manifest specifically for newer Android SDK?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I need to do permission request change for my Gallery/Photo permission because since Android 13 (SDK 33) you cant request `android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` to allow gallery browsing in case of photo upload. You need to use `android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"` instead. Question is if I can simply put it like this to manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
```

If it will affect older SDKs because this permission is new one added in SDK 33.
Or if I have to somehow if this in Manifest so this permission gonna be listed only for SDK >= 33

I tried this here but it seems like incorrect command (warning that its not allowed there)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission-sdk-33 android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

`android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES` is included in SDK >= 33, so older SKDs does not have this definition, hence it cannot be listed. I checked in the app settings of a device older than 33, and it is not listed, only `android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is listed. Then you need to programmatically ask for the correct permission depending on the SDK version of the device.